# Adding three.js to react-three-fiber

Tags: reactjs, three.js, react-three-fiber

Can someone tell me how I can combine three.js code with react-three-fiber? I saw that  tag is useful in such cases but still can't understand how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Import Three to use related stuff, like this

```
import * as THREE from 'three'
```

Then you can access THREE stuff such as THREE.Vector3

ideally you would want to write your three code in a hook like useEffec or useFrame or in any another way whichever is relevant.